# NameError: name 'np_array' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

Sometimes python makes me wonder. Yesterday I just executed the same codes on a different dataset, without any error. Today at first it gave me error that y_true is not defined, so I defined it as it appears in the codes.
Now it gives me the error on np_array:

```
import numpy as np
def y_true():
    np_array= np. add(y_true,y_pred)

no_of_pred =24
ind=72
y_pred= forecast(x_val,no_of_pred,ind)
y_true = y_val[ind:ind+(no_of_pred)]

# Lets convert back the normalized values to the original dimensional space
y_true = np_array.reshape(1, -1)
y_true= y_scaler.inverse_transform(y_true)

y_pred = np_array.reshape(1, -1)
y_pred= y_scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

I tried all methods found on the internet to solve it but was not successful.

Comment: Please post the full error message output.

Comment: You have y_true defined both as a function and a variable name. You also have a space between "np." and "add".

Comment: I don't see where you define np_array, either.

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 11
      8 y_true = y_val[ind:ind+(no_of_pred)]
     10 # Lets convert back the normalized values to the original dimensional space
---> 11 y_true = np_array.reshape(1, -1)
     12 y_true= y_scaler.inverse_transform(y_true)
     14 y_pred = np_array.reshape(1, -1)

NameError: name 'np_array' is not defined

Comment: Where in your code you assign a value to np_array?

Comment: Could you please post some sample input and what your expected output would look like. I'm confused how this code would run successfully.